# ConnectionManager can't find connection

Tags: user-profile-service, connection

I'm trying to get a connection from the connectionManager, but when I run the following code, I get my connection as null (which throws a nullreference exception later) Is there anyone who knows what the problem could be here? (can't debug... it's on production)

**Code**

```
private static void CreateProfileMapping(ProfileSubtypeProperty psp, ConnectionManager cm, string mappedName)
{
    Connection connection = cm["AD"];
    if (connection == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Connection 'AD' is null");// -> triggers
}
```

**Connectionmanager:**

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileConfigManager upcm = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);
ConnectionManager cm = upcm.ConnectionManager;
```

If I go to:

Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage service applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Configure Synchronization Connections

There's only one connection and it's called "AD". (synchronising works btw)

This worked perfectly on test-server, but it always has to be production that fails...

**ULS LOGS:**

> Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'test.Intra.Solution_User Properties' (ID: '45af143f-0a5f-4021-9bbf-3ea4d8869120') at URL http://intranet.test.    0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072
>   Calling 'FeatureActivated' method of SPFeatureReceiver for Feature 'test.Intra.Solution_User Properties' (ID: '45af143f-0a5f-4021-9bbf-3ea4d8869120').  0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072
>   LoadConnections failed trying to fill the connections list. Most likely during RetriveResources because of permissions --- {1}.  Available parameters: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException... 0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072
>   ... responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Ru...  0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072
>   ...ntime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at System.ServiceModel.Description.IMetadataExchange.Get(Message request)     at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.MetadataClient.Get(String dialect, String identifier)     at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.Client.ResourceManagementClient.SchemaManagerImplementation.RefreshSchema()     at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManager.get_SchemaManager()     at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManager..ctor(String typeName, LocaleAwareClientHelper localePreferences, ContextualSecurityToken securityToken)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ConnectionManag...  0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072
>   ...er.LoadConnections(Boolean fForUI) . 0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072
>   ConnectionManager.LoadConnections(): Could not find MOSS MA despite being marked as fully configured, was it deleted?   0dd8bdd1-4d5f-4a5e-9695-0bfe64791072

I guess it has something to do with this...

Is there anybody who knows a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you share the corresponding ULS and Event Logs for this..

Comment: still nobody who knows the anwser?

Comment: I am struggling with just about the same issue (though in PowerShell); only running as Farm account allows me to retrieve the connection managers.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. As explained by user17028, the solution for me was to run my code using the farm account.

FYI, my admin account:

- Has "Full control" through the "Permissions" button of the UPS ribbon.
- Has "Full control" through the "Administrators" button of the UPS ribbon.
- Is member of the local group "Administrators"
- Is member of the local group "FIMSyncBrowse"
- Is member of the local group "FIMSyncJoiners"
- Is member of the local group "FIMSyncOperators"
- Is member of the local group "FIMSyncPasswordSet"

But this is not enough. Don't know what permission the farm account has, that lacks my admin account...